# What does the priority means in the context of puppetlabs' hiera?

Tags: puppet, hiera

I was wondering if someone could hint me towards what does the priority stands for in Puppetlabs' hiera. Are there some explanation in hiera's documentation? Is it about the ordering of backends and datasources in the configuration file? Somehow I couldn't google that out.

UPDATE: To be more specific, what I do not understand is the way Hiera v1.3 assigns a level of priority for a data source. Such a priority which is refered by the Hiera v1 manual (https://docs.puppet.com/hiera/1/lookup_types.html) in : "Note that in cases where two or more source hashes share some keys, higher priority data sources in the hierarchy will override lower ones."

Comment: https://docs.puppet.com/hiera/3.2/hierarchy.html https://docs.puppet.com/hiera/3.2/lookup_types.html First result when googling 'hiera'. Also, this question is technically off-topic.

Comment: I did see this manual, but haven't found the answer there.

Comment: @AleksiRomanov, I don't understand how you can fail to see that the two documents Matt pointed out to you answer your question, especially the second.  If you have specific questions about what they say, however, then you could consider editing them into this SO question.

Comment: @AleksiRomanov Per your edited question, the documentation mentions that the order you list is the priority for the lookups, so the higher prioritiy will be preferred over the lower unless you specify some kind of merging mechanism.

Comment: Thanks. The manual does mention this, If you mean the order of the backends. I guess I need to assume the same applies to the data sources as well. Perhaps the reason the later is not stated implicitly in the manual is because that it is self evident for the most people.

Answer (score 1):

Hiera imposes implicit priority through lookup order. Data sources are visited in the order they are defined. That's why the most specific sources must be defined first, because they implicitly get the highest priority.

Comment: Thanks, Felix! Now that does sound pretty obvious to me as well, after I have played a little bit with swapping the order the data sources are defined in the hiera.yaml.